# How to integrate this

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate
$$
F_0a^2\left( -\frac{a}{2} \right) \frac{1}{\left( \rho ^2+\frac{a^2}{4} \right) ^{3/2}}
$$
This is in cylindrical coordinates, so $\rho$ represents a radius and I want to integrate the expression over a disk with radius a. The correct answer is
$$
-2\pi F_0a^2\left( 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right) 
$$
How can I find this answer? Any pointers would be much appreciated. I don't think sharing my attempts would do any good, I don't have much faith in them. But basically I've tried using a table of indefinite integral because I don't know how to start from scratch on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a substitution $u=\rho^2+\tfrac{a^2}{4}$. Don't forget the polar Jacobian $dA=\rho\,d\rho d\varphi$.

Comment: With that substition, and the Jacobian, I'll have to integrate $\frac{
\sqrt{u-\frac{a^2}{4}}}
{u^{3/2}}$ which is not easy either, I think.

Comment: the integrand becomes $du/(2u^{3/2})$

Comment: Yes you are right of course. Solved it now, thanks a lot.